# Create new dataframe column with 0 and 1 values according to given series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, boolean, nan

I have a dataframe as show below

```
df = 
                     value
2014-05-21 10:00:00    0.0
2014-05-21 11:00:00    3.4
2014-05-21 12:00:00    nan
2014-05-21 13:00:00    0.0
2014-05-21 14:00:00    nan
2014-05-21 15:00:00    1.0
..............
```

I would like to add two columns,

first one named "active" to switch the value to  1 (if df.value >=0 )and 0 (if df.value = nan), and the second one "unactive" to switch the value to  0 (if df.value >=0 )and -1 (if df.value = nan),so the new dataframe would be like

```
df_new = 
                     value   active  unactive
2014-05-21 10:00:00    0.0        1         0
2014-05-21 11:00:00    3.4        1         0
2014-05-21 12:00:00    nan        0        -1
2014-05-21 13:00:00    0.0        1         0
2014-05-21 14:00:00    nan        0        -1
2014-05-21 15:00:00    1.0        1         0
............
```

I try to use for loop, but it takes too much time when the time series is long. Does anyone know a better way to do it ? thanks for advance!

Comment: So if df.value < 0 and is not nan, what do you want 'active' to be? 1,-1, don't-care?

Comment: @smci good question, in the question I don't have negative number, but actually I want to point the value (>=0) equal to (=! nan).

Answer (score 2):

You may use `df.value >= 0` and use `astype(int)`:

```
In [44]: df['active'], df['inactive'] = (df.value >= 0).astype(int), -(~(df.value >= 0)).astype(int)

In [45]: df
Out[45]:
                     value  active  inactive
2014-05-21 10:00:00    0.0       1         0
           11:00:00    3.4       1         0
           12:00:00    NaN       0        -1
           13:00:00    0.0       1         0
           14:00:00    NaN       0        -1
           15:00:00    1.0       1         0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df['active'] = df['value'].notnull().astype(int)
```

and:

```
df['unactive'] = -df['value'].isnull().astype(int)
```

(Also you didn't specify what 'active' should be when df.value < 0 and is not nan. Should 'active' be? 1,-1, don't-care?)

Comment: @smci the output is not what OP asked for actually (im not the down voter by the way)

Comment: @RafaelC it is now actually. Again, comments are supposed to be constructive. It was trivial to convert to int. The hard part was formulating the expression.

Comment: `notnull`==`~isnull`....

Comment: Are you really arguing semantics when you had an *incorrect* answer that raised an error, and instead of downvoting, a user spent the time to explain why it would return an error?

Comment: This is an interesting part you mentioned... actually I would like to make new column "unactve" and switch the value to 0 (if df.value >=0 )and -1 (if df.value = nan), how can I write it ?

Comment: @Chi if you edit that second question into your question above, I can answer

Comment: I added the second answer, but in general chrisz is right, you should open a new question. But this was a trivial variation of the existing one.

Comment: @smci I saw it,  however it is a smart way, thanks :)